# Loop file items starting in defined index

Tags: python, python-3.x

im triying to iterate a file and start the loop in the second item of the list.

```
file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')
for line in file:
   # here i want to start the for in the second row
    line = line.strip('\n')
```

Any tips?

I tried doing:

```
start_row = 2
end_row = 10
file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')
for line in file[start_row:end_row]:
   # here i want to start the for in the second row
    line = line.strip('\n')
```

But i cant index a IOTextWrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the 1st record with `next` call and use context manager to cover file's `open/close` phases:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as f:
   next(f)
   for line in f:
       line = line.strip('\n')
```

Comment: Why do you add next(f) before the for loop? I want to skip the first line.

`with open(filename, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as f:
   for line in f:
     if start_row > line:
       next(line)
     line = line.strip('\n')`

Comment: @AlexRibeiro, nothing wrong there, cause `f` is iterator

Comment: Hey. Finally what i did was just use the `continue` like this:

`start_row = 2
end_row = 10
count = 0
file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')
for line in file:
    count =count+1
    if count < start_row or count > end_row:
          continue
    line = line.strip('\n')`